# Microsoft Graph REST API invalid client secret

Tags: azure, curl, office365api, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I have the following POST call I need to make. However, even if I provided the right client id and secret id, my call is getting rejected.

```
    curl POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/f02....e3/oauth2/token
 -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'  --data 'grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https://requestb.in/ac&
source=https://graph.microsoft.com&client_id=1e1....-913d9
&client_secret=YmbSFYz.....4Uk=&scope=mail.read&code=AaAAA........on0a569'
```

This is the error I receive:

```
    curl: (6) Could not resolve host: POST
    {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS70002: 
Error validating credentials. AADSTS50012: Invalid client secret is
 provided.\r\nTrace ID: 78d...a2b\r\nCorrelation ID: 
01....ab2\r\nTimestamp: 2016-12-14 01:46:47Z","error_codes":[70002,50012],"timestamp":"2016-12-14 01:46:47Z","trace_id":"78d....a2b","correlation_id":"018.....ab2"}
```

How could I resolve this ?

**EDIT:** I am trying to achieve the second section(i.e getting token) in [this documentation](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/get-started/rest)

Comment: Is your `redirect_uri` the same as the one you entered when you registered your app?

Comment: yes it is. If they are different, is that a problem ?

Comment: in that case it will say the wrong redirect_uri, not incorrect client secret.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The post you provided is leveraging AAD V2 endpoint. But according your code snippet, you were using V1 endpoint `https://login.microsoftonline.com/f02....e3/oauth2/token`. For acquire access token via V1 endpoint, you can refer to https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization for more details.

For the V2 authorization endpoint, you may check out the endpoints you are using:

`GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?...`

`POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token`

And also it is required a v2.0 ad application:

> This article assumes a v2.0 registration, so you'll register your app on the [Application Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Thank you for explaining this. After I tried v2.0 for authorization code first, I found the following errors: AADSTS70001: Application '1e15...53d9' is not supported for this API version.

Comment: It means that your AD application dose not support v2.0 endpoint. For registering a v2.0 application, you can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-v2-app-registration

Comment: as long as it can support both Office and Outlook, I can re configure the app to use v2.

Comment: i am afraid that currently we cannot.

Comment: I see. So I should use v1 if we want to access both outlook and office features. Right ?

Comment: application in v2.0 also can support both. But as your current application is in v1.0, so you can flow https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/authorization/app_authorization to acquire the token.

Comment: this is totally new application so I can re create one.

Comment: I followed the instructions based on the links you provided to migrate our app to v2 and I was able to get authorization code but when I tried to aquire token using adal4j libarary I got this error "Authorization Code is malformed or invalid". I add an app at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com ( I generated password and public/private key) I added a redirect url that is not https for local dev't. authority= https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token and I used the password as a client secret. Am not sure what I am did wrong.

Comment: It seems to be more related with language and library, you can ask a new question with more detailed messages and your key code snippet. Thanks.

Comment: I'll create a new question. Btw is the generated password the one i have to use in place of secret key ?

Comment: Yes, although I am not familiar with Java, but here is a sample in adal4j's repo at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/tree/dev/src/samples/web-app-samples-for-adal4j/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4jsample.

Comment: May be first I can try retrieving the token w/o the library. POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
what other parameters I need to use this ? only auth_code ?

Comment: FYI: here is an auth code OAQABAAIAAADRNYRQ3dhRSrm-4K-adpCJAMyNuNyavRpTYznFxh2O7-09BgfxLwhxWBnosrUFsPSfkzp8xxRBwbhk8cZWPGAJRQsdoe87w_Aw024-kclN9z1eERgDB1nWQwEwIdmdpuCM_jQElGM9kgs8i9G-lO5582RiSNdODiFyjMvhZcF49MICBkJCp8tgUBXyMwDfgTFFjCl8LJw6o4YBWg6IG3oA1gG_zQCTh9CsPdxmZiRoYRzxWn6r3lifk033kSc9egZe0mAMvSlCPvMzNhzXb0UDNEIHWpjQPhDt1jfymW_Slkz4lhdSy-nzAmMa2h19NQKeiqCKK6uSKMvme0eJhyex1twPn8x4fIXgIL0G5tHqy3TKjQNRK-QiQd5R0HY6IPfis5Lr6Pc06uY3uYKl3eiDbr5kvJTNiltd6xck7Is4yGfeI-C1o_A8J8KLVu2L5MtAHtHgWw-D7NuozNeCm-9d45h7-pjCC4qCG_zOXPlhozoQi8GX_0w04I6CB4G3UNVnOVDSegUdglVoJR-ADfjPsfl1YLRTXcWpAZ6imx6rONu76ez

Comment: xFQLxMCXLLiHdd8DWksQEPeQ04CafFumy4UBAxB09av2waTuop4bS0U0OqCmf1dt12aldP23U9CtzJqv2Xk5yVulMMepBSBsItQHZ7ujPTLORla195oL1ItftuyVi6huj75wBcIT9rK1vbDUgAA&session_state=b40c045e-e3ea-4f65-82e4-4e9d204d6be5

Answer (score 5):

It was due to client_secret. It may contain special characters.

The `encodeURIComponent()` function encodes a URI component.
This function encodes special characters. In addition, it encodes the following characters: , / ? : @ & = + $ #

Use the below one:

```
encodeURIComponent(client_secret);
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case:
in configs You have to use the client secret "Value", not ID.
This Value is visible only when it is generated. So you can copy/paste it, in this moment.

[image]

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/370508/getting-34invalid-client-secret-is-provided34-erro.html

Comment: People should look at this before anything else, this was my issue and it's so easy to copy the wrong field since everyone is used to copying whatever is on the far right of the screen during these setups.

Comment: Yes sure @J_L you are right. Effectively the MS gui is misleading.
I also had to regenerate it.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the npm package:

[Microsoft Azure Active Directory Passport.js Plug-In](https://github.com/AzureAD/passport-azure-ad)

with the v1 tenant-specific endpoint.

I was initially receiving the same error message after successfully logging into Microsoft: "Invalid Client Secret".

I was using the "Application ID" as the Client Secret.  Then I discovered that you need to go onto the "Settings" tab in the Microsoft Azure Portal

[Microsoft Azure](https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/ApplicationBlade)

and create a new "Key".  It doesn't matter what you name the key.  When you click the "Save" button, the value of the key will be filled in the web form.  Copy this right away, since it will not be displayed again if the web page is refreshed.

This is the "Client Secret" that you need to add to your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same problem today and with help of @muthu I sorted it out. 
When client secret is generated with app registration in azure. The secret is plain. But when to use it in the rest call you must urlencode it. 
Use an encoder like visual code or other. But it must be encoded else you ge the error

AADSTS7000215: Invalid client secret is provided.

Answer (score 0):

You need to base 64 encode client_secret in the POST body.

For example (using curl):

```
# Authn details
LoginURL='https://login.microsoftonline.com'
TenantDomain='********.onmicrosoft.com'
ClientID='********'
ClientSecret='********'

# Endpoint details
Resource='https://graph.microsoft.com'
TenantGUID="********"

# Authenticate with OAuth v1
URL="$LoginURL/$TenantDomain/oauth2/token?api-version=1.0"
json=`
curl \
        -s \
        -k \
        -X POST \
        -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        -u "$ClientID:$ClientSecret" \
        -d "grant_type=client_credentials" \
        -d "resource=$Resource" \
        -d "client_id=$ClientID" \
        --data-urlencode "client_secret=$ClientSecret" \
        $URL \
| python -m json.tool
`

access_token=`echo $json | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["access_token"]'`
token_type=`echo $json | python -c 'import sys, json; print json.load(sys.stdin)["token_type"]'`
#echo "access_token:$access_token"
#echo "token_type:$token_type:"

# Access resource
URL="$Resource/v1.0/directoryRoles/$TenantGUID/members"
curl \
        -s \
        -k \
        -X GET \
        -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
        -H "Authorization: $token_type $access_token" \
        $URL \
| python -m json.tool
```

Comment: Hi Paul, welcome to StackOverlfow and thanks for trying to help. However, answers with an explanation instead of only code have several advantages: They are more helpful for people who actually want to understand. They help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code-writing service. They better reflect your competence. They help verifying that the proposed solution makes sence, in case that it otherwise is non-obvious. Most of them mean that you are more likely to receive upvotes instead of downvotes. Would you like to harvest these benefits?